# Access 2010: How to make a query result updateable?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join, sql-update

I am working on my first Access 2010 database and have run into a problem editing the recordset returned from a query.

I have two tables, "drugs" and "warehouse_stock". In "drugs" I have the name of the drugs. In the other table I have their corresponding info. For those drugs that are in "drugs" table, the pharmacist will manage their quantity and the other relative values, like the input quantity of each drug with specific expiry date. Pharmacist can import to the "warehouse_stocK" the same info for a drug but with different expiry date.

Each row data in "warehouse_stock" is characterized by the active_substance/strength/strength_type/dosage_form. This four values must be the same in a row data in "drug". Pharmacist will have the ability to update the curr_date, in_quant, out_quant_expiry_date and brand (from "warehouse_stock") for existing row data and import new quantities of drugs that existing in "drugs".

My query right now is:

```
SELECT warehouse.active_subs,
   warehouse.strength,
   warehouse.strength_type,
   warehouse.dosage_form,
   warehouse.curr_date,
   warehouse.in_quant,
   warehouse.out_quant,
   warehouse.expiry_date,
   warehouse.available_stock,
   warehouse.brand,
   warehouse.ID
FROM   drugs
       RIGHT JOIN warehouse
         ON ( drugs.active_substance = warehouse.active_subs )
            AND ( drugs.strength = warehouse.strength )
            AND ( drugs.strength_type = warehouse.strength_type )
            AND ( drugs.dosage_form = warehouse.dosage_form )
WHERE  ( ( ( warehouse.active_subs ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_act_sub & "*" )
AND ( ( warehouse.strength ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_strength & "*" )
AND ( ( warehouse.strength_type ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_strength_type & "*" )
AND ( ( warehouse.dosage_form ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_dosage_form & "*" ) );
```

Is there a way to make the result updateable?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Zinonas

Comment: @Remou Yes, the warehouse.ID is unique index. And also the drugs.ID but I don't use it.

Comment: I am not sure why you have all those Like statements. Surely Strength should equal strength? Also, if you need four fields for a match to drugs, they should be indexed. Finally, why not just have the drug ID in the warehouse table and save yourself a good deal of duplication and pain?

Comment: How do i index the four fields for a match to drugs?

Comment: I found the indexing! So, how i use this index in my case? Sorry, I'm newbie :-(

Comment: The active_sub is not unique, either the strength etc. Only their combination is unique!

Comment: what do you mean by updateable? You need to update the values you selected with your select query?

Comment: @nawfal        Yes, the values i selected with my select query.

Comment: This is not possible. The view you get from your select query is readonly. You cant modify it. Moreover, if you need to update it in the first place with your own values, why fetch from db? In any case the best option is to populate the select results to a datatable and modify the values you want of that datatable

Comment: tell us which values from your select query you need to update

Comment: i want to update the values of: curr_date, in_quant, out_quant_expiry_date and brand. I want to make a database for a pharmacy, and i want to view the drugs and modify their quantities. I don't want to update the name/strength/dosage form of the drug which are in the drug table. I want the user only have permissions in the warehouse table.

Comment: @zinon I do not understand at all what is your requirement. Is it that you need to update the values in database? You're missing something very trivial. May be communicating better would do..

Comment: @nawfal Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @nawfal I have two tables, "drugs" and "warehouse_stock". In "drugs" I have the   name of the drugs. In the other table I have their corresponding info. For those drugs that are in "drugs" table, the pharmacist will manage their quantity and the other relative values, like the input quantity of each drug with specific expiry date. Pharmacist can import to the "warehouse_stocK" the same info for a drug but with different expiry date. To be continued...

Comment: @zinon instead of stating all these in comments, pls update and add details to your question. You can edit your own question. So that its clear for all

Comment: @nawfal Each row data in "warehouse_stock" is characterized by the active_substance/strength/strength_type/dosage_form. This four values must be the same in a row data in "drug". Pharmacist will have the ability to update the curr_date, in_quant, out_quant_expiry_date and brand (from "warehouse_stock") for existing row data and import new quantities of drugs that existing in "drugs". I hope that Ι made myself clear.

Comment: @zinon - Perhaps I'm missing something but why even have the join to `drugs` in the first place? It isn't used in the Select clause and isn't used in the Where clause.

Comment: @Thomas I think you 're right! That part is useless.

Comment: @zinon - Is the query without the Join now updatable?

Comment: @Thomas Yes it's updateable now, but is not what I'm expecting. Values in "warehouse_stock" are not corresponded to those in "drugs".

Comment: @Thomas Pharmacist must update the aforementioned values but also add new quantities of a drug ONLY IF drug is imported in "drugs", otherwise he won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<...>
warehouse.ID
FROM  warehouse 
LEFT JOIN Drugs
     ON ( drugs.active_substance = warehouse.active_subs )
        AND ( drugs.strength = warehouse.strength )
        AND ( drugs.strength_type = warehouse.strength_type )
        AND ( drugs.dosage_form = warehouse.dosage_form )
```

Comment: Why do you need the join to drugs? You are not using any of the fields. Why do you not include the drugs id in the warehouse table rather than duplicating data? Why have you so many LIKE statements?

Comment: The like statements are useful for my because i use a search engine to retrieve all the relative values from the db.I do not include drugs id in the warehouse table because i want to check four fields that are the same. Values are not unique by id but from the four fields. I use join to make this possible.

Comment: And the other questions? Especially, why not use drugs id and why the join?

Comment: The four fields: active_subs, strength, strength_type and dosage_form define the uniqueness of a row of data, not the id. For the join question, i edited the previous comment.

Comment: In that case you do not have a unique index if all you have is an index on a non-unique id. You will find it difficult to create an updateable query without unique indexes. I suspect your database design needs work. Consider adding a unique index to both tables.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses! I'll try to redesign my database!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not at all clear, and the title is very different from your textual description of the problem, and the provided query, even different.

If fields like active_subs, strength, strength_type, dosage_form are in both the tables which ought to have the same value, then your design is probably flawed. You should get rid of them from one of the tables. Why not have those fields in one table and join them by an id?

**Edit:** After endless discussion, here is what I understood. There is a big communication gap, so I am sure OP is not satisfied with this :)

```
SELECT warehouse.ID, drugs.quantity, warehouse.active_subs, warehouse.strength, 
       warehouse.strength_type, warehouse.dosage_form, warehouse.curr_date, 
       warehouse.in_quant, warehouse.out_quant, warehouse.expiry_date, 
       warehouse.available_stock, warehouse.brand --whatever values you want
FROM   warehouse
JOIN   drugs ON drugs.active_substance = warehouse.active_subs AND 
                drugs.strength = warehouse.strength AND 
                drugs.strength_type = warehouse.strength_type AND
                drugs.dosage_form = warehouse.dosage_form
WHERE  (....); --if ever there is one
UPDATE warehouse_stock SET curr_date=@curr_date, in_quant=@in_quant, 
                           out_quant=@out_quant, expiry_date=@expiry_date, 
                           brand=@brand;
```

I'm unclear according to what values OP wants to update. Use a suitable where clause in update query.

Comment: Unfortunately non of them is what I want to do!

Comment: I want to make a query to get the info of drugs and then have the ability to update some values.

Comment: do you want to update it to the underlying database? If so use an update query

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can I use an update query in the existing select query?

Comment: Yes you can, definitely!! but the trouble here is that the requirement is not at all query. What values you need to select before updating?

Comment: All the values from "warehouse_stock"

Comment: why do you want to select them before updating? You can update only the fields that are required. Do you need to select them before updating to process something on the values, then modify them and then update back? Is it?

Comment: I want to select them because there are many values in my database, so i want to retrieve those i need. Yes, that the process I trying to do, select them before updating to process something on the values, then modify them and then update back!!

Comment: Do you have an id which is a primary key field in warehouse and drugs table?

Comment: For both of them no. Each table has its primary key but they are not correlated.

Comment: Ok So you mean the id field of drugs table is not in warehouse table, instead it is related by a set of values like active substance, strength, dosage type etc right?

Comment: So what sorta processing are you going to do on the selected values? Can you tell us one likely demand? Is it gonna be something to deal with an `if` condition? Like if somevalue =2, then update somevalue with 3? will it be like `2 x somequantity of what is existing` etc?

Comment: For your first question, right! The two tables are related by a set of values like active substance, strength, dosage type.

Comment: For the selected values, I want to sum the available quantities and see if the result is less than 5.

Comment: So you mean you want to update the fields in warehouse table only if sum of few quantities is less than 5? what are those quantities if so?

Comment: No, I don't want to update only these fields. I just only want to see if the input quantities are more than 5. Then, I want to have the ability to update any field in warehouse table except the correlated fields.

Comment: Ok, what I am asking is "do you want to update the fields in warehouse field ONLY IF the sum of input quantities (which you get from Select) are greater than 5"?? if not greater, then leave without editing? Or is it that you want to view it anyway as well as edit?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I want to view it anyway as well as edit.

Comment: @zinon then its not a proper single query. You can run it as two separate queries. I'll edit it. Btw, what input you have initially? drug id? according to which value you need to select and edit?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your time! I really appreciate it! Select according drugs.active_substance+strength+strength_type+dosage_form. The initial input are also drugs.active_substance+strength+strength_type+dosage_form.

Comment: @zinon ok I get it the "according to" part. I am asking what input value you have initially? for example, `update sea set fish = 'sardine' where id = 2` it is about this id =2 i am asking about. or is it that you need to select and modify all the values warehouse table without any where clause?

Comment: OK! I need to select all the values warehouse table but modify all except the correlated field with the "drugs" table.

Comment: Access shows a warning that i can't have to sql statements in one query.

Comment: @zinon I am not very good at access UI, but certainly you can run the query from your application. May be the UI wizard is too poor in ms access. In any case I recommend using SQLite or something similar if its possible. Or you may get a better GUI administration tool for ms access. There are a couple

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this table updateable, you need to remove the join which was not used in the From nor Where clause (until now). However, you mentioned that you were trying to filter the `warehouse` results for only those that have a `drugs` value. To do that, you should use the Exists function which allows you to pass a correlated subquery (in that items in the inner query are matched against items in the outer query).

```
Select W.active_subs, W.strength, W.strength_type, W.dosage_form
    , W.curr_date, W.in_quant, W.out_quant, W.expiry_date
    , W.available_stock, W.brand, W.ID
From warehouse As W
Where  ( ( ( W.active_subs ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_act_sub & "*" )
AND ( ( W.strength ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_strength & "*" )
AND ( ( W.strength_type ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_strength_type & "*" )
AND ( ( W.dosage_form ) LIKE
"*" &
Forms!Pharmacy.form!pharmacy_warehouse_stock_Subform.form!warehouse_stock_dosage_form & "*" ) )
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From drugs As D1
                Where D1.active_substance = W.active_subs
                    And D1.strength = W.strength
                    And D1.strength_type = W.strength_type
                    And D1.dosage_form = W.dosage_form
                )
```

Comment: The "Exists" does not work. I get no results with this query.

Comment: @zinon - If you eliminate the other elements of the Where clause so that the only thing left is the Exists clause, do you get results?